# (Python) Spyder not starting

Tags: python, spyder

for some reason my Python IDE spyder isn't working anymore. When trying to start it, it does not open. Trying `~$ spyder` in the console gives to following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 2, in <module>
from spyderlib import start_app
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/start_app.py", line 13, in <module>
from spyderlib.config import CONF
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/config.py", line 433, in <module>
subfolder=SUBFOLDER, backup=True, raw_mode=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/userconfig.py", line 111, in __init__
self.load_from_ini()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/userconfig.py", line 150, in load_from_ini
self.read(self.filename())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
self._read(fp, filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /home/rk/.spyder2/.spyder.ini
[line 317]: 'shor'
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall spyder` and even `sudo apt-get purge spyder && sudo apt-get install spyder` but that didn't help either. Nor did I find a solution to my problem online.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You need to find & fix the error around line 317 of your `/home/rk/.spyder2/.spyder.ini` file: if you need help with that, please [edit] your post to include the relevant section of the file. Since it's a personal configuration file (in your home directory) it won't be affected by reinstalling the package.

Comment: I did `sudo gedit PATH/.spyder2.ini` to take a look at line 317. It just says `shor`. I do, however, not know what it is supposed to say, so i don't know what to change it to. Can't i just delete the file (the entire directory) and have it recreated with a new install?

Comment: I don't know if it works that way here, but this thread can be closed (?). I did simply delete my entire .spyder2 directory. Maybe not the most subtle solution be it worked. It was created anew when i reinstalled spyder. For some reason my entire .spyder.ini was corrupted (wrong), there were multiple lines missing at the end.

Comment: That's fine: at worst, you may have lost any personal spyder preferences/settings that you had set. There is no reason to close the thread - feel free to add (and accept) your own solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had a related problem. Spyder (version 2.2.5) crashed. I tried to reopen it after rebooting my computer, but nothing happened- clicking on the symbol in the launcher did nothing, also just typing

```
spyder
```

in a command line did not result in the GUI being fired up, it also did not result in an error message. However, typing

```
spyder --new-instance
```

resulted in the GUI being fired up.
Looking into the file

```
start_app.py
```

in the directory

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/
```

it became clear the the following lines of code were the problem:

```
if CONF.get('main', 'single_instance') and not options.new_instance \
  and not mac_app:
    # Minimal delay (0.1-0.2 secs) to avoid that several
    # instances started at the same time step in their
    # own foots while trying to create the lock file
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1000, 2000, 90)/10000.)

    # Lock file creation
    lockf = get_conf_path('spyder.lock')
    lock = lockfile.FilesystemLock(lockf)

    # lock.lock() tries to lock spyder.lock. If it fails,
    # it returns False and so we try to start the client
    if not lock.lock():

        if args:
            send_args_to_spyder(args)
    else:
        atexit.register(lock.unlock)
        from spyderlib import spyder
        spyder.main()
else:
    from spyderlib import spyder
    spyder.main()
```

So, some instance of spyder was created previously and has created the file

```
spyder.lock
```

which resulted in the empty list of arguments given by the command

```
spyder
```

being passed to spyder, resulting in no action:

```
send_args_to_spyder(args)
```

Hence, renaming the spyder.lock file made spyder fire up again just using the app launcher or a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem (kind of):

Did `sudo gedit /home/USERNAME/.spyder2/.spyder.ini` to look at the file, which basically contains your local spyder preferences/settings. If you know what the erroneous lines are supposed to say, you can simply change them.

Since i did not, I simply deleted my entire .spyder2 folder. It was then created anew when i did `sudo apt-get purge spyder && sudo apt-get install spyder`.

Simply doing `sudo apt-get purge spyder` or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall spyder` won't work since it doesn't affect your personal configuration file. You have to either repair or delete the .spyder.ini manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I tried to open Spyder from terminal, I got following error message:

```
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /home/.spyder2/spyder.ini
    [line 55]: 'font/italic'
```

My solution:

1. Open the spyder.ini file using `nano /home/.spyder2/spyder.ini`
2. Then delete the [line 55]: 'font/italic'
3. Save the file

Done! I could open Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

This is a development on the [fix proposed by Wilhelm Braun](https://askubuntu.com/a/735959/446253).

In my case, I did not get any error message. Simply and silently, Spyder 2.2.5 was not starting off, whether I used the command line or the desktop menu.

The command `l ~/.spyder2` showed a dangling (red-coloured) symlink `spyder.lock@`.

Deleting this file made Spyder start as expected.